# Integral as a member of the closure of the convex hull of the integrand

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is compact and metric and let $g:X\to\mathbb R$ be a Borel map. Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$. Then it seems that
$\int_Xgd\mu$ is a member of the closure of the convex hull of $\{g(x):x\in X\}$ and I was wondering if anyone could provide a reference containing a proof of this result.

Comment: Isn't this a simple consequence of the fact that $ \inf_X g = \mu(X) \inf_X g \le \int g d\mu \le \mu(X) \sup g = \sup_X g$?

Comment: This seems the right answer to me. Thanks.

Comment: What if one poses the following slightly different question? Suppose that $X$ is compact and metric and let $f,g:X→\mathbb R$ be two Borel maps. Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$. Is $(\int fd\mu,\int gd\mu)$ in the closure of the convex hull of $\{(f(x),g(x)):x∈X\}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not have a reference, but a simple proof. Let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an (integrable) Borel map. Assume that $\int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu$ does not belong to the closed convex hull of $\{f(x) : x\in X\}$. Then we can use a separation theorem to get $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with
$$ \Big\langle \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu, y \Big\rangle_{\mathbb R^n} > 0 \ge \langle f(x), y \rangle_{\mathbb R^n}$$
for all $x \in X$. However, by linearity of the integral, we have
$$\Big\langle \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu, y \Big\rangle_{\mathbb R^n} = \int \langle f, y \rangle \, \mathrm{d}\mu \le 0,$$
since the integrand is non-positive. This is a contradiction.